# Is `nodetool disableautocompaction` persisted between restarts of Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise

Is `nodetool disableautocompaction` persisted between restarts of Cassandra? Useful to know in case Cassandra would run out of memory or something.

Comment: Why would you want to disable autocompaction for long periods?

Comment: To enable incremental repairs.

Answer (score 1):

No, to disable it across restarts you need to set it in the cassandra.yaml

Comment: Thanks! You might also be able to answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47866555/how-do-i-disable-autocompaction-in-cassandra-yaml.