# How do I disable autocompaction in `cassandra.yaml`?

Tags: cassandra, datastax, datastax-enterprise

https://stackoverflow.com/a/47837940/260805 hints that it should be possible. I would like to disable it for a longer period of times (~2 days) when enabling incremental repairs.

Comment: I think you should read this [blog post](http://thelastpickle.com/blog/2017/12/14/should-you-use-incremental-repair.html) from The Last Pickle before going ahead. Incremental repairs are no longer recommended for production.

Comment: I agree firmly with above to avoid incremental repairs as of 3.11 still

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(Disclaimer: I'm a ScyllaDB employee)

As far as I know you can disable autocompaction in the following ways:

1. For a column family (Table), by setting its strategy to NullCompactionStrategy.
   (I think this one is supported only in Scylla, but not in Cassandra)
2. Using nodetool: `$ nodetool <options> disableautocompaction -- <keyspace>  <table> ...`
   (I think this one is supported only in Cassandra, but not in Scylla)